# Wordnet with JWNL, getting it set up

Tags: java, wordnet

I've been experimenting with Wordnet on Python, and decided to jump to Java because of the apparently better API's. I'm trying to replicate the top answer to this question> [Getting all nouns related to a verb in WordNet using JWNL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275392/getting-all-nouns-related-to-a-verb-in-wordnet-using-jwnl)

But, I'm using IntelliJ Idea, and it cannot resolve the symbol "proc" in the first line

```
IndexWord indexWord = proc.lookupBaseForm(POS.VERB,"bear");
```

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple, but I was able to remove the errors by the other symbols with

```
import net.didion.jwnl.data.IndexWord;
import net.didion.jwnl.data.POS;
import net.didion.jwnl.data.Synset;
import net.didion.jwnl.data.Word;
```

I can't seem to contact the person who originally wrote the answer and I can't comment on his answer since I don't have the necessary reputation.

Also, I assume I have to specify the Wordnet library location? On http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/ it says to use

```
System.setProperty("wordnet.database.dir", "C:\WordNet-3.0\dict\");
```

But then again, that's the JAWS library and I'm trying to work with the JWNL library...

I hope this isn't confusing, I just recently (in the last few days) started using JAVA...

UPDATE I found this previous question and I did the recommendations, but I'm still getting a file not found exception when I do the initialize function, like the one here: [Runtime error in using wordnet through JWNL, error in the props file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839275/runtime-error-in-using-wordnet-through-jwnl-error-in-the-props-file)

Comment: Off the topic of your question, but do you have a link explaining why Java APIs "apparently" better than Python (I'm not a fan of either, just curious.) You might also be able to answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/25114018/841830

Comment: @DarrenCook Actually, sorry, I think I was mistaken, I didn't figure out how to use JWNL, but I used Rita and it appears that it's not actually better or faster than what I was doing in python. I guess what I'm really looking for are different algorithms (like the lesk measure) for python and when I couldn't find any, and java api's apparently had them, I just presumed they were better. Do you know if there is anything for python that resembles the functionality offered with this library? > https://code.google.com/p/ws4j/

Comment: A bit of link-following brought me to here: https://github.com/alvations/pywsd  Is that what you were after?

Comment: @DarrenCook Hey, I think that's it! I'm still really slow with coding and figuring stuff out, so it'll take me a while to confirm, but thanks again!

Comment: @DarrenCook Actually, I was looking into it, and it looks like it only compares words with sentences, and I'd like to basically type in a word and have it compared to every other word in the db to find if any are above a certain predefined lesk number...